# how to send base64 images and textvalues as json object in angular js and spring mvc 4

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have converted my image to base 64 in angular js  and send it to my controller but the controller does not get the image when decoded  in the right format.The image in my angular js was 106kb but when i converted my image in base 64 the image size was only 8 bytes in controller

**The html file**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="extensions/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-base64/angular-base64.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="testcontrol">

    <input type="text" ng-model="A.username" placeholder="Enter Username" required>
    <input type="password" ng-model="A.password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
    <input type="file" ng-model="B.img" placeholder="Browse image" required>

    <input type="button" value="Send" ng-click="setValues()" />
    <input type="button" value="Send" ng-click="getValues()" />

    <script>


        var app = angular.module('myApp', ['base64']);



        app.controller('testcontrol', function($scope, $http,$base64) {
            $scope.setValues = function() {
                alert("post");
                var a=$base64.encode($scope.B);
                $scope.A.image=a;
            console.log(a);
                $http({
                    method : 'POST',
                    url : 'form/post',
                    headers : {
                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                    },
                    data : $scope.A
                }).success(function(data) {


                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                });
            };

            $scope.getValues = function() {
                alert("get");
                $http.get('form/get').then(
                        function(response) {
                            if (response) {
                                alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                            }
                        });
            };

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Controller in spring**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/form")
public class Form {
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/post" ,method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@RequestBody TestDto test)
    {
logger.info("username"+test.getUsername());
logger.info("password"+test.getPassword());
logger.info("image"+test.getImage());

byte[] decodedValue = Base64.getDecoder().decode(test.getImage());


try {
    FileOutputStream f=new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/shalom/Pictures/tets.png"));

    f.write(decodedValue);
    f.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it works if you override the default request transformer in your post request:

```
$http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'form/post',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    },
    transformRequest :  [function (data, headers) {
        //just send data without modifying
        return data;
    }],
    data : $scope.A
}).success(function(data) {
```

By default angular tries to dectect if the request's data contains JSON and modifies the data.

For more information see [angular $http api docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) section "Transforming Requests and Responses"

Comment: when i tried this code i get http 400 OST http://localhost:8080/app/form/post 400 (Bad Request) Th angular request is not going to controller

Comment: Your spring controler must be something like this                    @ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value ="/form/post", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public void receiveBase64(@RequestBody String base64){
  System.out.println(base64);
 }